# How to retrieve specific Json Elements into an array in java

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

I have the following json returned from Elasticsearch. What is the fastest and most efficient way to retrieve the `highlight.name` value into a `List<String>`, in Java?

```
{
      "timed_out": false,
      "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
      },
      "hits": {
        "max_score": 6.512624,
        "hits": [
          {
            "_index": "shops",
            "_type": "shop",
            "_id": "AVfRy7_-rRRgqtjX0fQt",
            "_score": 6.512624,
            "highlight": {
              "name": [
                " <em>Smartwatch</em> Phone"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "_index": "shops",
            "_type": "shop",
            "_id": "AVfRy7_9rRRgqtjX0fGz",
            "_score": 6.446859,
            "highlight": {
              "name": [
                " <em>Smartwatch</em>"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "_index": "shops",
            "_type": "shop",
            "_id": "AVfRy7_-rRRgqtjX0fVa",
            "_score": 3.7999475,
            "highlight": {
              "name": [
                " 3G <em>Smartphone</em>"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: you can use Jackson library to convert json into java object, create a pojo mapped to the json, get json converted to java object, get the required field.

Answer (score 1):

Use JSONObject for that:

```
    // jsonResult is a string that contains your ES response
    JSONArray json = (new JSONObject(jsonResult)).getJSONObject("hits").getJSONArray("hits");

    List<JSONArray> result = new ArrayList<>();
    json.forEach((j) -> {
        JSONObject highlight = ((JSONObject) j).getJSONObject("highlight");
        result.add(highlight.getJSONArray("name"));
    });

    // Outputs [[" <em>Smartwatch<\/em> Phone"], [" <em>Smartwatch<\/em>"], [" 3G <em>Smartphone<\/em>"]]
    System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Jackson libraries provide json simple format.

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.enable(SerializationConfig.Feature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
Object json = om.readValue( output, Object.class );
System.out.println( objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(json));
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to benchmark the alternatives to see which is faster and more "efficient" (whatever that means) for your use case. The following may be faster then going via Jackson but is more fragile given the use of a regular expression.

```
    List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"highlight\".*?\"name\": \\[\\s*\"(.*?)\"\\s*\\]", Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(json);

    while (m.find()) {
        matches.add(m.group(1));
    }

    System.err.println(matches);
```

Comment: Hi David, I tried the regex but didnt find any matches. And thing is I m not familiar with regex so cannot really tweak it.

Comment: Works for me on the sample you provided, prints `[ <em>Smartwatch</em> Phone,  <em>Smartwatch</em>,  3G <em>Smartphone</em>]` . Maybe you reformatted the json before running the sample code?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [jsonPath](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) library, it's fastest way to read a value from json just in one line of code.

```
List<String> highlightResults = JsonPath.parse(/*yourJsonString*/).read("$..name", List.class);
```